# How do hard links, symbolic links, and ACL folder permissions interact?

Tags: permissions, security, symlink, acl, hard-link

This one was a bit tricky for me to realize, but I came across a very weird behavior involving [ACL extended file permissions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Access_Control_Lists) and hard/symbolic links. I'll do my best to keep my question short and to the point, but I first have to show you an example of my current situation, as I don't know whats happening or what it is called.

---

Suppose we have a system with two users, let's call them `alice` and `bob`, who to a certain degree share a folder called `stuff` with the following permissions:

```
bob@server:~$ getfacl /home/stuff getfacl: 
Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: home/stuff
# owner: alice
# group: bob 
user::rwx
group::-wx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:user:bob:rwx
default:group::-wx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---
```

As you see, the owner of the folder is `alice`, but bob can write stuff in there and make it executable, so that `alice` could run in (+x flag). However, because of ACL, everytime bob writes/copies a file into `stuff`, the permissions of the file get altered and end up being as follows. Assume we create a file in `bob`'s home dir and move it to `stuff`.

```
bob@server:~$ touch myfile
bob@server:~$ chmod 777 myfile
bob@server:~$ ls -la myfile
-rwxrwxrwx 1 bob bob 0 myfile

bob@server:~$ mv myfile /home/stuff/myfile
bob@server:~$ ls -la /home/stuff/myfile
-rwxrwx---+ 1 bob bob 0 /home/stuff/myfile
```

As you can see, even though `myfile` is in the folder `stuff`, `alice` would have no access to it. Because the file belongs to `bob:bob`, `alice` would have to access it with the "others" file permissions, which are `---` as per the last of the above `ls` commands. Still, because `alice` is the owner of the folder, she can delete them (although I get a warning about `myfile` being protected).

Now comes the fun part. If instead of moving/copying the `myfile`, I create a hard link to it, watch what happens.

```
bob@server:~$ ln myfile /home/stuff/myfile
bob@server:~$ ls -la /home/stuff/myfile
-rwxrwxrwx 2 bob bob 0 /home/stuff/myfile
```

Apparently `alice` can read and use it. In fact, if tested it on my system and she can indeed. Notwithstanding, a symbolic link seems not to work at all.

```
bob@server:~$ ln -s myfile /home/stuff/myfile
bob@server:~$ ls -la /home/stuff/myfile
lrwxrwxrwx 1 bob bob 4 /home/stuff/myfile -> /home/bob/myfile
```

This time, although the link also has all permissions set to `lrwxrwxrwx` (precisely because its a link and anyone has to be able to follow it to get the permissions) `alice` can not execute it, only delete it.

---

**My questions:**

- Why can I "skip" the ACS permissions with a hard link in the first
  place?
- And why does this same trick not work with symbolic links?
- Is this intentional, or is it a security hole?

Answer (score 3):

As `alice` has write permission to `stuff/` directory, alice can modify its contents even if she isn't the owner of the files.

When using Linux ACLs, when file is created (or copied, as copy creates new file at target) permissions are applied as described by [`man acl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/acl.5.html). Moving a file with `mv` [*preserves permissions*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149798/239817) when the file can be moved without copying. Looks like for some reason `mv` can not move the file and does a copy instead, since ACLs are applied to `myfile`.

Creating a hard link is quite different. Creating a hard link creates a directory entry (at the target directory), which points to the *same inode* as the original file, in other words, the same file exists in more than one directory. File permissions, both ACLs and traditional UNIX permissions, are stored in the inode. As both `/home/stuff/myfile` and `/home/bob/myfile` point to the same inode, any change in either will reflect to the other. This is why `alice` can access the hard link. The permissions of `/home/bob/myfile` (777) are the same as the permissions of `/home/stuff/myfile`.

Symbolic links instead points to the target path. Accessing the file that the symbolic link is pointing to requires the same permissions as accessing the target file. Possibly `alice` doesn't have search (execute bit) access to `bob`'s home directory, and therefore access fails.

Comment: Wow! I now see it much clearer. However, is this a security hole? As it appears that bob wasn't meant to put executables inside the shared folder, but with the hardlink trick he can

Comment: Owner can change permissions anyways (bob can change the permissions of files he owns in the shared folder). Also, if bob can create files (with permissions of his liking) in directory it doesn't really make a difference if the file is a hard link or not.

Comment: (Also, an user can create a hardlink to any file on same filesystem, which can be a problem if root re-assigns ownership of files in the new location. For example explained in [Dan Walsh's blog](https://danwalsh.livejournal.com/64493.html).

Comment: @sebath I've tried it but it's not the case. For any reason (maybe there is an additional policy on the server I'm not aware of), bob can't change the ownership of any file inside the shared folder. I'll try to inquiry the server admin to see whether this is because ACL or if there is something more going on.

Comment: bob shouldn't be able to change ownership, but any permissions on files he is owner of.

Comment: @sebasht Indeed. But because the file belongs to bob:bob, and the ACL mask prevents any access for "others" to the file, alice is not allowed to execute it. She is neither user bob, nor in the group bob, nor can execute it as "others". Unless I understood something wrong, of course. That's the problem I'm facing. However, I can overcome it with hard-links (but not symlinks), which led mi to the present question.